# How to add new rows and columns in pandas with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a data frame with stock returns as so (not real figures):

```
                AAPL      GOOG  ...        FB            NTFLX
Date                            ...                           
2016-03-01  0.001123 -0.001124  ...  0.004314         0.001234
2016-03-02 -0.000423 -0.000125  ... -0.005534        -0.002163
2016-03-03 -0.000714  0.001121  ... -0.009162        -0.005241
2016-03-04 -0.007522  0.005126  ... -0.007142        -0.003642
2016-03-07 -0.001324 -0.009123  ... -0.005352         0.001337
                 ...       ...  ...       ...              ...
2019-10-25  0.005234  0.000326  ...  0.000123        -0.002827
2019-10-28  0.006274 -0.000706  ... -0.001376        -0.006558
2019-10-29  0.000016 -0.000822  ...  0.005583        -0.003556
2019-10-30 -0.000411  0.003213  ... -0.009223         0.002566
2019-10-31  0.002146  0.001757  ... -0.002734        -0.003144
```

I would like to create a new data frame with the same rows and columns but I'd like to build it through a for loop like:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.index:
   for column in df.columns:
      new_df.loc[row] = {column: data_df[column]}
### data_df is just a data frame that looks like the one above but with other stock info
```

I know what I'm coding is wrong but is there a way to do this? Each iteration of the loop will first append a new row (such as a date), and then will keep appending columns (stock tickers) with a value (such as stock prices/ratios/etc). It will continue to do so until the very last date.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain more what you want at the end, you want to replace the value in each cell by a dictionary? or do an mathematical operation?

Comment: Do you want the transpose DataFrame? `df.T`?

Comment: So the process I'm thinking of is: 1. empty dataframe, 2. create a new row. 3. create n number of columns. 4. add values. 5. create another new row. 6. add values to the new row for all columns.

something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.index:
   for column in df.columns:
      new_df.loc[row, column] = df.loc[row, column] 
      # Here df can be any dataframe from wich you want to copy values
```

With this code what you are doing is copying values line by line, column by column.

Also, try reading [loc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to better understand how it works .

Comment: why do this¿? new_df=df?

Comment: how would I add a value to the empty row and column? In my head I think this code just populates the columns and rows, but how do I get the values in there with iteration? Thanks

Comment: It is populating the "new_df" iteratively. Print the new_df each step to see each iteration result.